# Retrieving an item from DynamoDB based on id and transforming the item

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jackson, amazon-dynamodb, objectmapper

I'm having a bit of trouble with transforming my item to a "Student" with Jackson ObjectMapper. I've gotten the method to actually get the right item based on the id-parameter sent from the front. So this is the method that works, but doesn't return anything, because I just wanted to test if it works.

AwsService:

```
public void getStudent(String id){

    Table t = db.getTable(studentTableName);

    GetItemSpec gio = new GetItemSpec()
            .withPrimaryKey("id", id);

    Item item = t.getItem(gio);
    System.out.println("Student: "+item); // <--- Gives the correct item!

}
```

But now I need it to return a "Student", so instead of void, it should return a Student:

```
public Student getStudent(String id){

    Table t = db.getTable(studentTableName);

    GetItemSpec gio = new GetItemSpec()
            .withPrimaryKey("id", id);

    Item item = t.getItem(gio);

    //Problem starts here, unsure of how to do. As is, getS() is underlined as error
    Student student = mapper.readValue(item.get("payload").getS(), Student.class);

    return student;
}
```

Just as a reference I'll add my working method for retrieving all students. So as you can see, I tried to use the same mapper.readValue as in the method for retrieving all students:

```
public List<Student> getStudents() {

    final List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
            .withTableName(studentTableName);

    ScanResult result = client.scan(scanRequest);
    try {
        for (Map<String, AttributeValue> item : result.getItems()) {
            Student student = mapper.readValue(item.get("payload").getS(), Student.class);
            students.add(student);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return students;
}
```

Comment: Replace item.get("payload").getS() with "item.getJSON("payload").substring(1)" and try how it goes. Hope all the attributes names in Dynamodb and Student class matches! Otherwise, you may get some other error.

Comment: Okay, that helps! It prints the correct data in the console, but with '\' in between. Error code 92 like this: [link](http://yuluer.com/page/dggeggjd-unexpected-character-code-92-in-jackson.shtml) I tried using escapeJson for my "student" but gives underlined error at the escapeJson. Any ideas?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the escape character in the console output as it is a standard way to print the JSON string. The primary aim is to return the Student object with all the values populated. As an alternative, you can print the Student object.toString() which would print the data without escape characters.

Kindly accept the answer if it resolved your original problem.

Comment: Of course I would accept the answer if I had known it was correct. I just assumed that it didn't solve my problem, as the data does not get passed to the front. When sending the whole list, it gets through to the front, and if I print the whole list it in the console in the backend, it's without the escape characters... so I assumed that was the problem with this solution...

Comment: Still, the front end doesn't get the student data? If yes, have you tried to print the student object at the end of the method to check whether it has the data as expected? I am totally concentrating on getStudent(String id) as we are discussing about the back end method here. There can be so many things which could go wrong in between that I am not aware of. As long as the student object data is printed correctly at the end of the method, then the original problem is resolved.

Comment: I am talking about the back.When I print out the list at the end of my getStudents method in the back, it gives the data without the backslashes and no problems. When I try to do the same for getStudent, it prints the correct data BUT with the backslashes. If I also mention about the front, I receive the list fine. But retrieving one student doesn't work. Of course I can also have some problem in the front, even though I can't spot anything now. Therefore I was just wondering if the backslashes has anything to do with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is the correct method for me:

```
public Student getStudent(String id) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException  {

    Table t = db.getTable(studentTableName);

    GetItemSpec gio = new GetItemSpec()
            .withPrimaryKey("id", id);

    Item item = t.getItem(gio);

    Student student = mapper.readValue(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(item.getJSON("payload").substring(1)), Student.class);

    return student;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace item.get("payload").getS() with "item.getJSON("payload").substring(1)".

Comment: The backslashed WERE the problem as I suspected. Below my own answer. I had to nest the unescape json in my method.